# Why does npm run dev Not working end up in errors [code 1]

Tags: php, laravel, docker, npm, fortify

Hello i started using laravels php framework recently and now i keep getting this issue trying to run a command followed by different tutorials creating a register and login form with laravel fortify jetstream.
By trying to execute this comand:

`npm run dev`

i keep getting this problem

`

```
root@b0f498dc21b4:/var/www/html# npm run dev

> dev
> vite

file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/html
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vite

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-22T19_48_34_550Z-debug.log
root@b0f498dc21b4:/var/www/html#
```

`

Also as I run command npm update I get this-
`

```
root@b0f498dc21b4:/var/www/html# npm update
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'laravel-vite-plugin@0.6.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@3.2.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 131 packages in 42s

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

`
and in the package-lock.json the versions seems right for my small understanding

`

```
"node_modules/vite": {
            "version": "3.2.4",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vite/-/vite-3.2.4.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-Z2X6SRAffOUYTa+sLy3NQ7nlHFU100xwanq1WDwqaiFiCe+25zdxP1TfCS5ojPV2oDDcXudHIoPnI1Z/66B7Yw==",
            "dev": true,
            "dependencies": {
                "esbuild": "^0.15.9",
                "fsevents": "~2.3.2",
                "postcss": "^8.4.18",
                "resolve": "^1.22.1",
                "rollup": "^2.79.1"
            },
            "bin": {
                "vite": "bin/vite.js"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": "^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0"
```

`

tried many different solutions from stack and github but none match my problem or dont work.
Please help,
thank you in advance for even reading

Comment: What version of node (`node -v`) and npm (`npm -v`) are you using?

Comment: root@b0f498dc21b4:/var/www/html# node -v
v12.22.12
root@b0f498dc21b4:/var/www/html# npm -v
7.5.2 . But the thing is that in package-lock.json the versions are the same as they require. Btw I updated the question with another snipet of the terminal

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10668 - You probably need to upgrade your version of node

Comment: `"node": "^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0"` node definitely needs to be updated

Comment: any suggestions how? bcs i updated my windows node to 18.12.1 but cant get it to update my laravel docker project